# Unable to insert about 100k recs from my local mysql to Google SQL cloud platform. It takes hours. A similar operation to AWS takes few minutes

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I'm not able to copy(insert) about 100k recs from my local mysql to Google SQL cloud platform. It takes hours. A similar operation to AWS takes few minutes.

Comment: so, what is your question here?

Comment: Why does it take so long? Has anyone else also faced similar problem and how to reduce the time to insert to minutes.

Comment: So I'm doing an equivalent of 

[local-server]# mysqldump -u root -ppassword mydb  mytable| mysql -u root -ppassword --host=173.194.x.x -C mydb

The mytable contains 100K recs and data is less than 15MB in size. This operation takes more than 10 hours. The remote server (173.194.x.x) is Google SQL Cloud.

Comment: What products are you using? Google Cloud SQL and Amazon RDS? When doing a bulk import, you'd get better performance for Cloud SQL by uploading a dump to Google Cloud Storage and importing from that.

Comment: @cflewis Yeah, I used google cloud storage and it improved the performance. I wish you had pointed me to it few days earlier. My thanks to you as I feel assured that I have hit the right approach.